# Is it possible to generate multiple HTML reports with different configuration after the same execution? jmeter-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

**I'm using jmeter's maven plugin and I would like to generate two different HTML reports from the same execution log.** Is it even possible to do this using this plugin?

This is my pom.xml and I'm not sure how to create a second report with a different output folder and title for example.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
            <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jmeter.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configuration</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>configure</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>tests</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jmeter</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>check-results</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>results</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <propertiesUser>
                    <thread.number>${thread.number}</thread.number>
                    <rampup>${rampup}</rampup>
                    <jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>CA Dashboard</jmeter.reportgenerator.report_title>
                </propertiesUser>
                <ignoreResultFailures>true</ignoreResultFailures>
                <generateReports>true</generateReports>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently no, the report generation happens at the same time the test is run.

When the following issues have been fixed it may be an option:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/328
- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/391
- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/issues/316